# Return html file depending on parameter

Tags: nginx

I want nginx returns  different html depending on url parameters
for example:

for url http://example.com/blog?page=1 I want it to send to browser file /var/www/mysite/pages/page1.html

for http://example.com/blog?page=2 - /var/www/mysyte/pages/page2.html

And I want user to see url http://example.com/blog?page=1 in his browser.
Is it possible?

Comment: It's certainly possible, but what should it do for `/blog`, `/blog?page=oops`, etc.?

Comment: For /blog /var/www/mysite/pages/page1.html, for wrong page 404 or html with error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you (also with the requirement of fallback to page1.html):

```
server {

  root /var/www/mysite/pages;

  location /blog {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /page$arg_page.html break;
    try_files $uri /page1.html;
  }

}
```